# Creating multiple neural net arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm learning python but cannot get my head around making multiple arrays for neural nets the examples I get tend to evolve around 1 neural array example and I want to create many. The below is one neural net how to I expand it in numpy so it's many thanks in advance.Im trying to create a swarm of neural net arrays each with its own input hidden and output layers 8)

```
import numpy as np

epochs = 10000         # Number of iterations
inputLayerSize, hiddenLayerSize, outputLayerSize = 2,2,1


X = np.array([[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]])
Y = np.array([ [0],   [1],   [1],   [0]])

def sigmoid (x): return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))      # activation function
def sigmoid_(x): return x * (1 - x)             # derivative of sigmoid
                                                # weights on layer inputs
Wh = np.random.uniform(size=(inputLayerSize, hiddenLayerSize))
Wz = np.random.uniform(size=(hiddenLayerSize,outputLayerSize))


for i in range(epochs):

    H = sigmoid(np.dot(X, Wh))                  # hidden layer results
    Z = sigmoid(np.dot(H, Wz))                  # output layer results
    E = Y - Z                                   # how much we missed #(error)
    dZ = E * sigmoid_(Z)                        # delta Z
    dH = dZ.dot(Wz.T) * sigmoid_(H)             # delta H
    Wz +=  H.T.dot(dZ)                          # update output layer #weights
    Wh +=  X.T.dot(dH)                          # update hidden layer #weights

print("------")                # what have we learnt?
#Walk-through
print(Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the whole network in a function and pass the variables as arguments such that you can have as many networks as you need.

There is a mistake in your code:

```
def sigmoid (x): return 1/(1 + np.exp(-x))      # activation function
def sigmoid_(x): return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x)) # derivative of sigmoid
                                            # weights on layer inputs
```

Comment: It seems to coverage correctly babu what's the mistake? 8) Secondly, when try and create a larger array it won't calculate e=y-z 8) ps thanks for your help so far